# Cadastrar no banco de dados quando o usuário fecha janela do navegador

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que precisa ter registrado o tempo que o usuário ficou logado no site. Quando ele faz um login eu cadastro no MySQL a hora do login e seu ID, o problema está na hora que ele fecha o navegador, em JQuery tentei usar beforeunload:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
  //faço um post para alimentar o banco de dados
});
```

Dessa forma que fiz funciona quando o usuário da um F5 ou escreve um novo endereço na barra do navegador. Mas não esta funcionando quando o usuário fecha o navegador (pelo X).

Existe uma outra forma para contornar isso? Talvez algo pelo lado do servidor (estou usando PHP e session para o login), ou uma função em Jquery que detecta o fechar?

Comment: Já pensou em adicionar uma coluna com o nome UltimaAtualização e no fronte vc faz uma função que a cada 1 minuto ou mais ele manda request para uma pagina X que atualiza a coluna no UltimaAtualização assim vc adiciona um evento no banco para rodar a cada 10 minutos e compara se a UltimaAtualização e > que 10 minutos se for ele saiu 1 minuto depois da ultima UltimaAtualização

Comment: Bela idea essa ein? Meu medo é sobrecarregar o servidor, o cliente estima uns 10.000 usuários logados ao mesmo tempo, precisaria de um bom servidor para suportar isso né?

Comment: mano se o fluxo e desse nivel eu recomendo vc utilizar socket pq ai e em real time e quando ele desconectar automaticamente  ele upa a hr de deslog

Comment: Pode só me dar uma luz o quer seria? Só pra eu saber o que buscar e aprender. Confesso que não conheço

Comment: real time socket php com banco de dados, procura por isso